# How to print what I want after stepi and nexti in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm running the *stepi* and *nexti* commands in GDB. Currently they print the address like this:

```
(gdb) stepi
0x08043ae7 in ?? ()
(gdb) nexti
0x08043ae8 in ?? ()
```

Instead of that, I'd like to get the current instruction printed:

```
(gdb) stepi
=> 0x8043ae7:   push   %eax
(gdb) nexti
=> 0x8043ae8:   push   %ebx
```

I know that I can get the desired lines by running `x/i $pc`. How do I get them automatically after `stepi` and `nexti`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get them automatically after `stepi` and `nexti`?

This will do *almost* what you want:

```
(gdb) display/i $pc
```

The difference is that it will display the next instruction every time GDB stops, not just after `stepi` and `nexti`.

You should also be able to use `hook-nexti` and `hook-stepi` if you really want the `x/i` to only fire for these two commands. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html).